Attempt to debug streamlit on VSC raises error
I have the following launch.json:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "debug streamlit",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "streamlit",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "$(file)"
            ]
        }

    ]
}

But I get the following error when attempting to run VSC debug on Streamlit:
(Venv) workdir$  cd /workdir ; /workdir/Venv/bin/python /home/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-linux-x64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 52265 -- -m streamlit run \$\(file\) 
Usage: streamlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET [ARGS]...
Try 'streamlit run --help' for help.

Error: Streamlit requires raw Python (.py) files, but the provided file has no extension.
For more information, please see https://docs.streamlit.io

What do I have to change to make it work?


        "args": [
            "run",
            "$(file)"
        ]


You should replace $(file) with ${file} in your launch.json file.
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "debug streamlit",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "streamlit",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "${file}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

